# Jung2: how to connect all nodes at once

Tags: java, algorithm, jung

I would like to ask is there any way to connect all nodes using one and simple method from Jung2 API. I would like to get full graph for the nodes that I did place on my canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating a complete graph for a given set of nodes is pretty trivial (and also fairly uncommon), so JUNG doesn't provide a method to do this.  The code would look something like this:

```
for (V v : g.getVertices()) {
  for (V w: g.getVertices()) {
    g.addEdge(createEdge(), v, w);
  }
}
```

(You'd need to supply an implementation of createEdge().)

Comment: Thx for your answear! I would also like to ask is there any way to make SimpleGraph in Jung2 as using SimpleGraph<V,E> interface as it is said in tutorial ain't working.